# Multiple JQuery versions

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, macos, google-chrome, meteor

I am developing a meteor application on my mac and I am using Chrome as my browser.

Now I'm getting the error `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3`

If I do `$.fn.jquery` in the console, I get `3.1.1`.

But I'm using `jquery@1.11.10` in my `package`-file and in `versions`, there is also `jquery@1.11.10`. I don't know from where the 3.1.1.-version is comming...

Comment: Maybe you have script tag in your html file with https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js, try opening developer tools press CTRL+SHIFT+F type "fn.init" and press enter, you should see the file where jQuery come from then you can search for filename.

Comment: `fn.init` gives me `Uncaught ReferenceError: fn is not defined`

Comment: @jcubic is trying to say that you should search for "fn.init" in the developer console. Don't try to "execute" the function, press the key combination, and search for it.

Answer (score 0):

I used firebug's network tab to see what js files loaded and that is how I found we were running two versions of jQuery in one of our applications.

It does give you the URL pattern for where the file is coming from which can help in finding the file.